# How to get 100% height from the parent DIV to child DIV using CSS flex

Tags: css, flexbox

In example code block, there is a DIV name "left-line" (red color line). I need to stretch the height of that DIV according to "content" DIV's height.

Please I need to achieve this, Without having CSS "position" and "border" attributes. I'm using CSS flex.

```css
.parent {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
}

.left-line {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 0 0 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-line">s</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the height:100% from your .left-line class

```css
.parent {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: orange;
}

.left-line {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 0 0 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-line">s</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```